# Systematically altering SQL Server database names based on a common string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a sql query I've been using for a long time to drop databases that are created when a simulation file is run. I use this query in case something goes wrong and the database isn't dropped and then returns erroneous data. However, I recently decided that I want to keep at least the previous database from the last time I ran this file so I thought I'd just add a section to the query that alters the name of the database so that my drop query doesn't touch it.

Here's the query I use to drop the databases. (The plurality is the most important part of this question)

```
--declare variables
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(200); --database name from reports
DECLARE @query1 nvarchar(max); --query to drop databases
DECLARE @query2 nvarhcar(max); --query to fore drop databases if query1 fails

--declare the cursor by selecting database names with the TESTTAG tag.
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE '%TESTTAG%'

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 --keep going as long as there is more in the list of db names

BEGIN
    --drop the databases
    SET @query1 = 'DROP DATABASE ['+ @dbname +']'
    SET @query2 = 'USE master
                  ALTER DATABASE ['+ @dbname +']
                  SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
                  DROP DATABASE ['+ @dbname +'];'
    EXEC(@query1)
    EXEC(@query2)

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I figured I would use the same basic structure to create my "rename database" query. But replace the contents of the `@query` variable to an `alter database` query.

I found this example to use as a format for a good query to use to alter the name.

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE Database1
SET SINGLE_USER 
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
EXEC master..sp_renamedb 'Database1','Database2'
GO
ALTER DATABASE Database2
SET MULTI_USER 
GO
```

However, I realized a problem. The way I'm planning on changing the names of my reports is to simply change the tag that is in every database name. So instead of "TESTTAG" I might use "EXPTEXT". But "TESTTAG" is located inside of the `@dbname` variable.

Comment: So...what is your question?

Comment: are you looking for a string replace function in sql server?

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server's own backup mechanism? I can imagine renaming will be faster, but is it really worth the trouble of rolling your own backup mechanism?

Comment: FYI I never rename a database. It doesn't change the names of the underlying MDF and LDF files and that can lead to name collisions. A better strategy is to detach, change the file names, and attach under the new name.